# How to parse xml data in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to parse xml data in android. I have seen this project: [here from github](https://github.com/foamyguy/stacksites) which teaches how to parse xml data in listbox. However, I want to get xml data to different strings. Although, I have used pretty much the same code as in the github project but I only get error and the app stops responding.

Code:

```
public class Main extends Fragment {
    android.view.View myview;
    EditText number;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen, container, false);
        number = (EditText) myview.findViewById(R.id.number);
        XmlParser par = new XmlParser();
        number.setText(par.getStackSitesFromFile(getActivity().getBaseContext())
            .get(0).getLink()); **Error here**
        return myview;
    }
}
```

XmlParser.java

```
public class XmlParser {
    static final String KEY_SITE = "rate";

    static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";

    static final String KEY_LINK = "Rate";

    static final String KEY_ABOUT = "Date";

    static final String KEY_IMAGE_URL = "Time";



    public static List<HandleXML> getStackSitesFromFile(Context ctx) {
        // List of StackSites that we will return

        List<HandleXML> stackSites;

        stackSites = new ArrayList<HandleXML>();

        // temp holder for current StackSite while parsing

        HandleXML curStackSite = null;

        // temp holder for current text value while parsing

        String curText = "";
        try {

            // Get our factory and PullParser

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();

            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            // Open up InputStream and Reader of our file.

            FileInputStream fis = ctx.openFileInput("/sdcard/rates.xml");

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            // point the parser to our file.

            xpp.setInput(reader);
            // get initial eventType

            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            // Loop through pull events until we reach END_DOCUMENT

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                // Get the current tag

                String tagname = xpp.getName();
                // React to different event types appropriately

                switch (eventType) {

                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                    if (tagname.equals("test")) {
                        curStackSite = new HandleXML();
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    //grab the current text so we can use it in END_TAG event
                    curText = xpp.getText();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("test")) {
                        stackSites.add(curStackSite);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_NAME)) {
                        curStackSite.setName(curText);
                    } else if (tagname.equals("Rate")) {
                        curStackSite.setLink(curText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_ABOUT)) {
                        curStackSite.setAbout(curText);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_IMAGE_URL)) {
                        curStackSite.setImgUrl(curText);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // return the populated list.
        return stackSites;
    }
}
```

And finally, HandleXml.java

```
public class HandleXML {
    private String name;
    private String rate;
    private String date;
    private String time;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setLink(String rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public String getAbout() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setAbout(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getImgUrl() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + rate;
    }
}
```

Xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2016-09-07T05:50:08Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
<results>
<test>
<Name>EUR/USD</Name>
<Rate>1.1251</Rate>
<Date>9/7/2016</Date>
<Time>0:56am</Time>
</test>
<test>
<Name>EUR/USD</Name>
<Rate>1.1253</Rate>
<Date>9/7/2016</Date>
<Time>0:56am</Time>
</test>
</results>
</query>
```

The error is in the first fragment of code in: `number.setText(par.getStackSitesFromFile(getActivity().getBaseContext()).get(0).getLink());`

Comment: What is the error? I guess it is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, if so it means that your List is empty

Comment: I have just tested your parser with the XML file that you provide and it works as expected on my side, I have a List with 2 instances of HandleXML

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Exactly. The error is: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0.

Comment: it means that your list is empty so get(0) throws this exception, for some reason getStackSitesFromFile returns an empty list. Check if you get an exception while trying to parse your XML file

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I get the exception immediately when the fragment is to show up (as I set number.setText() in onCreateView). I still cannot understand why the list returns empty, and what should I do to fix it.

Comment: Please add the stack trace to the question; as it is put, it is very difficult to analyze the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arraylist returns empty because FileInputStream *fis* is set to open a file which contains path separator (**/**) , and it causes

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /sdcard/rates.xml contains a path separator

. You have to use 
`FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (new File("/sdcard/rates.xml"));` instead. Do not forget to close fis by `fis.close();`

Final code for XmlParser will be:

```
public class XmlParser {
static final String KEY_SITE = "rate";

static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";

static final String KEY_LINK = "Rate";

static final String KEY_ABOUT = "Date";

static final String KEY_IMAGE_URL = "Time";

FileInputStream fis;


public static List<HandleXML> getStackSitesFromFile() {
    // List of StackSites that we will return

    List<HandleXML> stackSites;

    stackSites = new ArrayList<HandleXML>();

    // temp holder for current StackSite while parsing

    HandleXML curStackSite = null;

    // temp holder for current text value while parsing

    String curText = "";
    try {

        // Get our factory and PullParser

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();

        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        // Open up InputStream and Reader of our file.

        fis =  new FileInputStream(new File("/sdcard/rates.xml"));

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        // point the parser to our file.

        xpp.setInput(reader);
        // get initial eventType

        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        // Loop through pull events until we reach END_DOCUMENT

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

            // Get the current tag

            String tagname = xpp.getName();
            // React to different event types appropriately

            switch (eventType) {

            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                if (tagname.equals("test")) {
                    curStackSite = new HandleXML();
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                //grab the current text so we can use it in END_TAG event
                curText = xpp.getText();
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("test")) {
                    stackSites.add(curStackSite);
                } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_NAME)) {
                    curStackSite.setName(curText);
                } else if (tagname.equals("Rate")) {
                    curStackSite.setLink(curText);
                } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_ABOUT)) {
                    curStackSite.setAbout(curText);
                } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_IMAGE_URL)) {
                    curStackSite.setImgUrl(curText);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        fis.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.i("Problem closing", "Closing fis");
    }


    // return the populated list.
    return stackSites;
}
}
```

And then set number.setText() like that: `number.setText(par.getStackSitesFromFile().get(0).getLink());`